# I cant collect answer from my variables in for loop

Tags: python, loops, variables, scope

Please can someone help with my homework....I'm stuck and i need serious help. Below is the question:
for each room, ask for the room name (e.g. lounge, dining room) and the number of walls in the room:  For each wall, ask the height and width of the wall in metres.  Calculate the total surface area of the walls in square metres.
I cant add the numbers in my for loop because the for loop repeats the variables do as well so i cannot record the first answer in my first input because i cannot do this i cannot find the total surface area

Below my code:

```
numofrooms = input("num of rooms:")
n = int(numofrooms)
for n in range(n):
    input("name of room:")
    numofwalls = input("num of walls:")
    wall = int(numofwalls)
    for wall in range(wall):
        height = input("height of wall:")
        height = int(height)
        width = input("width of wall:")
        width = int(width)
        sa = int(height) * int(width)
    tsa = sa * int(numofwalls) * int(numofwalls)
```

Comment: Hint: Push the intermediate results to a list, then sum the list when you are done looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are calculating the surface area for each room (sa = width*height) but not totaling it correctly afterwards (ie. storing that value in a total).

The code below calculates the sa of every room by continually adding the sa of all walls for said room (The "for wall in range(numOfWalls):" loop). It needs to calculate the sa for all rooms, so it add every rooms surface area to a total variable (as described in other answers)

```
numOfRooms = int(input("num of rooms:"))
tsa = 0
for n in range(numOfRooms):
    input("name of room:")
    numOfWalls = int(input("num of walls:"))
    sa = 0
    for wall in range(numOfWalls):
        height = int(input("height of wall:"))
        width = int(input("width of wall:"))
        sa = sa + (height * width)
    tsa = tsa + sa
```

I've combined some lines to make things a little nicer to look at

Answer (score 2):

As you calculate the surface area of each wall, add that value to a variable.  At the end of your program, print that variable.

You almost had this with your `tsa` variable, but your code *replaces* the previous value of `tsa` instead of *adding* to it, and it should be indented within the `for wall in...` loop.

Comment: thank u...i also just realized i had typed this in before but i didnt think it was right so i deleted it

Answer (score 1):

To sum up values, use an additional variable:

```
sa_sum = 0
for _ in range(wall):
    sa = do_your_calculation()
    sa_sum = sa_sum + sa
```

Answer (score 1):

```
numofrooms = input("num of rooms:")
n = int(numofrooms)
tsa = 0
for n in range(n):
    input("name of room:")
    numofwalls = input("num of walls:")
    wall = int(numofwalls)
    for wall in range(wall):
        height = input("height of wall:")
        height = int(height)
        width = input("width of wall:")
        width = int(width)
        sa = int(height) * int(width)
    tsa += sa * int(numofwalls) * int(numofwalls)
```

You just need to sum `tsa` with each loop, rather than resetting it each time. You were close.

Comment: I assume so. I didn't test it.